# Tomcat never returns 503

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, tomcat9, http-status-code-503

I am experiencing some issues when my webapp is getting lots of simultaneous connections (ie. when the service is starting).
I am expecting at a certain level of charge to have tomcat answer that he can't take more, by answer an error with **code 503**.
I have read the documentation and understood (I hope) the usage of **maxThreads**, **acceptCount** and **maxConnections**.
I also read lots of posts:

- [How can I produce a 503 error locally with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156502/how-can-i-produce-a-503-error-locally-with-tomcat)
- https://netflixtechblog.com/tuning-tomcat-for-a-high-throughput-fail-fast-system-e4d7b2fc163f

but I was not able to reproduce a tomcat answering 503, even by setting maxThreads to 1.

As I find lots of posts on how to solve 503 issues, I am obviously missing something... Can anyone help?

Comment: Try getting a thread dump of tomcat JVM to verify that maxThreads is in effect.

Comment: I activated JMX so I can observe what happens. I have a jmeter simulating 1000 users calling a webservice in loop.
I have 117 live threads (DB thread pool, scheduled tasks...) but only 1 is a https-jsse-nio...exec, whereas I have up to 150 of them with default config (starting with 25).

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing when trying to connect directly to Tomcat.

I've long used Apache HttpServer as a front-end to Tomcat and seen 503 when all available processes and threads are exhausted.  I'd expect to see some means by which Tomcat can at least be configured to reject additional concurrency.

From my naive reading of the source code I also can't see how 503's occur due to concurrent requests.

And when I try to force 503's from a test environment by constraining the connector (i.e. minimizing threads, accept count, and max connections), putting sleeps in a test JSP page, and hitting that page with lots of concurrent requests -- I get client side timeouts but no 503's.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).